# IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 refusing to create PASSIVE MODE FTP connections

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, iis-7.5, perl

I'm attempting to get an FTP client written in perl to transfer files from an IIS 7.5 FTP server using passive mode.

I've configured the FTP server as per instructions and have also configured Windows Firewall to allow this type of traffic. I have validated that the firewall is behaviong correctly by checking to ensure there are no blocked packets in the logs. I have verified the that FTP control channel is being opened on Port 21.

I believe the client is being told by IIS which port to connect on for passive mode and IIS is refusing to allow this connection.

The perl log looks like:

```
C:\cygwin\Perl\lib\FMT>perl FTPTest.pl
Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(2.77)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.64_01)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.31)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.28)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)<<< 220 Microsoft FTP Service
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)>>> USER ftpuser
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)<<< 331 Password required for ftpuser.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)>>> PASS ....
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)<<< 230 User logged in.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)>>> CWD /Logs
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)<<< 250 CWD command successful.
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)>>> PASV
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xxx,xxx,xxx,160,41).
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x20abac0)>>> RETR filename.txt
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at C:/Utilities/strawberryper
l/perl/lib/Net/FTP/dataconn.pm line 54.
```

IIS logs look as follows:

```
2010-10-02 17:40:06 xx.xxx.xx.xx - yy.y.yy.yy ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a - -
2010-10-02 17:40:06 xx.xxx.xx.xx - yy.y.yy.yy USER ftpuser 331 0 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a - -
2010-10-02 17:40:06 xx.xxx.xx.xx MACHINENAME\ftpuser yy.y.yy.yy PASS *** 230 0 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a / -
2010-10-02 17:40:06 xx.xxx.xx.xx MACHINENAME\ftpuser yy.y.yy.yy CWD /Logs 250 0 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a /Logs -
2010-10-02 17:40:06 xx.xxx.xx.xx MACHINENAME\ftpuser yy.y.yy.yy PASV - 227 0 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a - -
2010-10-02 17:40:27 - MACHINENAME\ftpuser zz.z.zz.zzz 41001 DataChannelClosed - - 64 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a - -
2010-10-02 17:40:27 xx.xxx.xx.xx MACHINENAME\ftpuser yy.y.yy.yy ControlChannelClosed - - 64 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a - -
2010-10-02 17:40:27 xx.xxx.xx.xx MACHINENAME\ftpuser yy.y.yy.yy RETR filename.txt 550 1236 0 27a48c9b-9dce-4770-8bcf-fc89f2569b1a filename.txt -
```

We've managed to see this issue with other FTP clients also, I don't think its something funny in Perl. I've been informed that this works fine in the IIS 6 FTP server. I'm wondering if there is something we're missing here.

Comment: Can you provide any other details from the "other FTP clients"?  The error you posted doesn't seem (although maybe PERL just isn't handling it well) to be an FTP error per-se.  But a real FTP client log might shed more light on it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  IIS FTP 7.5 is configured by default to allow only ACTIVE FTP not Passive I believe - at least in two default installs I have done.  Perhaps your script is getting hung up on this.  The IIS website http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings/ helped me immensely--though my problem was with a regular FTP client (filezilla) not PERL it should apply in this case.  Look at especially Step 3: Configure Windows Firewall Settings

Comment: The: `227 Entering Passive Mode (xx,xxx,xxx,xxx,160,41).` line indicates that IIS actually entered passive mode and was waiting for a passive FTP connection to being, so this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've met with similar problems with other ftp server software.

you may need to do port mapping if your ftp server is behind NAT.
you may also need to check the port the server used for passive mode and port map it.
Also check firewall that those ports are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with a Perl script.
I was connecting from a private ip address.
In passive mode the the public ip address is returned when issuing the PASV command!
Solution was to set Passive => 0 to use active mode when inside the firewall and use Passive => 1 when outside the firewall.

Comment: Actually I think you're on the right track. You can specify your IP address in IIS. If this FTP server is behind a NAT you'll have to specify the public IP address. Can @Campbell let us know if you see a public or private IP address in the 227 response?

Answer (score 0):

Try using IIS configuration editor navigate to System.applicationHost/sites -> siteDefaults ->ftpServer-> security-> dataChannelSecurity and disable matchClientAddressForPort and matchClientAddressForPasv. This was my fix when going from IIS 6 to IIS 7.5